# Allocating individuals to places using a random method

Tags: r

I have 100 workers and I want to allocate them randomly to 5 groups,ABCDE. But the places have a specific capacity as follows A= 23, B= 37, C= 10, D=20, E=10. So I need to have the following table (part of table)

```
Worker  Group
1   A
2   D
3   E
4   D
.   
.   
.   
.   
.   
.   
98  C
99  B
100 E
```

How I can do this in R?

Answer (score 4):

I think the most compact solution for `df$Group` is

```
sample(rep(LETTERS[1:5], c(23,37,10,20,10)))
```

If you do not require those specific numbers, but rather just the probabilities be the same then you need to sample with replacement and use the argument `probs` as follows

```
sample(LETTERS[1:5],100, replace = T, prob = c(.23, .37,.1,.2,.1))
```

---

Comment: Yes, that is what I wrote. If you want to sample with a specific probability, with the caveat that you not require a specific number in each group, one could use the second snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a straight forward solution:

```
#define your groups based on desired sizes
groups<-c(rep("A", 23), rep("B", 37), rep("C", 10), rep("D", 20), rep("E", 10))

#now random sample to define split
Group<-sample(groups, 100, replace=FALSE)

df<-data.frame(Worker=1:100, Group)
```

Comment: The number of C is 9 , not 10, Not sure why?